# Template deduction from pointer to base-class member

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, template-argument-deduction

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Problem in the template deduction from pointer to base-class member - &DerivedClass::BaseClassMemeber.

Full example:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <tchar.h>

struct Base
{
   int BaseClassMember;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
};

template<class T1, class T2>
void Test(T1& Param1, T2 T1::* Param2)
{
}

int _tmain()
{
   Derived inst;
   // Compile error E2285 Could not find a match for 'Test<T1,T2>(B,int A::*) - BCC32
   // Error 1 error C2782: 'void Test(T1 &,T2 T1::* )' : template parameter 'T1' is   ambiguous - MS VS8
   Test(inst, &Derived::BaseClassMember);

   // Works great
   Test<Derived>(inst, &Derived::BaseClassMember);
   return 0;
 }
```

I can found several workarounds, e.g. Additional Test function overloading with one more template parameter, static_cast, implicit partial specialization (Test).

But i am interested in reasons **why complier just can't use class which was explicitly specified in &DerivedClass::BaseClassMemeber**. That is the question. And if you have more elegant solution for problem, welcome.

Comment: You may also find it interesting your "Works great" *doesn't* on clang 3.3. `Test<Base>`, however, *does*.

Comment: Ok this excludes one workaround, but nevertheless where is the problem?

Comment: For your workaround with another template parameter, I'd say implement it as `template<class T1, class T2, class T3> typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T2 T3::*, T2 T1::*>::value, void>::type Test(T1& Param1, T2 T3::* Param2)`, or if C++11 is an option, `template<class T1, class T2, class T3> auto Test(T1& Param1, T2 T3::* Param2) -> decltype(Param1.*Param2, void())`. They will help you if you add additional overloads of `Test`, where you want overload resolution to ignore invalid attempts calls to this particular `Test` (`Test(inst, &Unrelated::ClassMember);`).

Comment: Didn't know about std::enable_if, thanks. Unfortunately c++11 is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&Derived::BaseClassMember` has type `int Base::*`, not `int Derived::*`. Quoth the Standard:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`. [... skip ...] [Example:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B : A { };
... &B::i ...             // has type int A::*i
```

> — end example]

You have to cast the value to `int Derived::*` if you need this type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i found this link after your hint. Leave it here for detailed information. http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3772.pdf